# How do i make it print both my selection and change due?

Tags: vb.net

I want it to tell me my choice and the amount of money I have left that I put in the machine

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim moneyInserted As Double
        Dim selectedSoda As String
        Dim changedue As Double = 0.5


        Console.WriteLine("Insert Money")
        moneyInserted = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine("Type A for Crystal Clear Pepsi, B for New Coke, and C for OK Soda")
        selectedSoda = Console.ReadLine()
        Dim theSoda As String = sodaMachine(selectedSoda, moneyInserted, changedue)
        Console.WriteLine("Your choice is {0}", sodaMachine(selectedSoda,moneyInserted, changedue))
        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

    Function sodaMachine(ByVal selection As String, ByVal money As Double, ByVal change As Double) As String
        If money >= 0 Then
            Return (money - change)
            If selection = "A" Or selection = "a" Then
                Return "Crystal Clear Pepsi"

            ElseIf selection = "B" Or selection = "b" Then
                Return "New Coke"

            ElseIf selection = "C" Or selection = "c" Then
                Return "OK Soda"
            Else
                Return "Invalid Selection"
            End If
        Else
            Return "Not enough money"
        End If

    End Function

End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make sodaMachine() return Tuple

```
Dim retval = New Tuple(Of Double, String)()
retval.Item1 = (money - change)
retval.Item2 = "Crystal Clear Pepsi"

Return retval
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx